# How to add pseudo elements to range slider thumb

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I have three files

test1.html

```
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
...
<div class="divOne"></div>
```

test2.html

```
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
...
<div class="divTwo"></div>
```

main.js

```
document.querySelectorAll('.divOne');
document.querySelectorAll('.divTwo');
```

Then I would get an error in the test1.html file that divTwo cannot be found.
In test2.html I would get the error that divOne cannot be found.

How can I make JavaScript code optimal that I can include my JavaScript file for reusable components on any page, but if something doesn't exist because I don't use it in the file, nothing should happen?

Comment: Using `querySelectorAll()` I would expect it to simply return an empty NodeList. Can you give some more context in your main.js as to how you're using these calls?

Comment: Hello @badg, your question is very generic, you have to specify what kind of reusable component it is ? what is its context ? etc.. for example : an open/close actions on a modal can not be applied in the same way on a tooltip, that's what i mean by "context" . For your small example, if i was in your place i will check if those queried elements (.divOne and .divTwo) exists or not with a simple `if..else..` . You should write your code and include your logic context to be able to help you or fix your issues. PS: you are using `.querySelectorAll(..)` it returnes a list of nodes.